# Quickly filling up excel cells from a Array

Tags: vba, excel

I generate arrays from a external data tool and now want to fill the cells up using the data in the arrays. I have written the following code.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
   Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
   For i = LBound(Price) To UBound(Price)
   .Cells((Lastrow + 1), 1) = Price(i)
   .Cells((Lastrow + 1), 2) = Quantity(i)
   Lastrow = Lastrow + 1
   Next i
End With
```

All the arrays are of same length and I have around 25 odd arrays to work with. The code works fine but the problem I am facing is of speed. It takes me around 5-6 hours to fill the sheet once with around 3000 as the length of array. Please suggest your best way. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use `transpose` method to dump the array into the range object of you desire?

Comment: If you had a 4-fold improvement in performance, it's still taking 75 to 90 minutes.  I timed the `Application.Transpose` approach against the 2-d array approach on a selection of 25 columns by 3000 rows and the former approach pretty consistently took 1/8 longer.  If that holds for you, your execution time would drop by another 8 to 10 minutes (assuming all of the execution time is attributable to filling the data into the worksheet, which is perhaps unlikely: if I divide the execution times by the number of iterations, I get 0.09 and 0.08 seconds per iteration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have number of arrays (25) with different data (e.g. Price, Quantity, SomeOtherArray) as per your question. As per my comment above.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetData()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim arrPrice As Variant
Dim arrQty As Variant

Set ws = Sheets(3)
'-- starts at zero index
arrPrice = Array(50, 60, 70, 75)
arrQty = Array(250, 100, 50, 200)

'-- change columns as per your needs
LastRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'-- UBound + 1 is because the array starts at zero index above
ws.Range("B1").Offset(LastRow).Resize(UBound(arrPrice)+1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrPrice)
ws.Range("B1").Offset(LastRow, 1).Resize(UBound(arrQty)+1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrQty)

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Glad it helped, feel free to comment and ask questions if you have any doubts or need help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how to populate to a range from an array without looping:

```
Sub PopulateFromArray()
    Dim MyArr As Variant
    MyArr = Array("Hello", "World", "This is some", "Text")
    Range("A1").Resize(UBound(MyArr) + 1, 1).Formula = Application.Transpose(MyArr)
End Sub
```

We are using resize to resize the range to populate using the upper boundary of the array. We add one to it because it is option base 0. We transpose the array because by the nature of an array the data goes across and we need it to go down. If we wanted to span columns instead of rows we would need to double transpose it like this:

```
Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(MyArr))
```

Answer (score 3):

you can dump an array to a worksheet range very simply like this:

```
range("A1:B5").value = myArray
```

you can populate an array conversly:

```
dim myArray as variant
myArray = range("A1:B5").value
```

I use this method very frequently, I hardly ever work with data on a worksheet, I prefer to take it into an array first then work with the array.

Comment: That creates a 2D array with option base 1. As a test run your code to populate an array but use the range "A1:A4" and put a stop after you set MyArray then in the debug window enter ?MyArray(0) to get the bottom value. it errors, Then try ?MyArray(0,1) it errors, then try MyArray(1,1) and it will give you the first value. It's much harder to query a 2D array in your code than it is a 1D Array, Doable but harder.

Comment: I almost always work with a table of data, so a 2D array works for me. You're right though, if you're working with purely 1D data then there are easier ways.

Answer (score 2):

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
   NextRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
   num = UBound(Price) - LBound(Price)
   .Range(.Cells(NextRow, 1), .Cells(NextRow + num, 1)) = Application.Transpose(Price)
   .Range(.Cells(NextRow, 2), .Cells(NextRow + num, 2)) = Application.Transpose(Quantity)
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

To fill a range of N rows by M columns, put the data into a 2-dimensional array of the same size, then assign that array to the Value property of the range.

```
ReDim varValues(1 To lngRowCount, 1 To lngColCount)
```

Or

```
ReDim varValues(0 To lngRowCount - 1, 0 To lngColCount - 1)
```

I presume you can handle populating the array.  Then:

```
Set rngTheRange = 'I presume you can handle this, too
rngTheRange.Value = varValues
```

Here is an example that uses this technique to fill the current selection with values 0 through N - 1, where N is the number of cells in the selection:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub X()
    Dim rngCurrent As Range

    Dim lngRows As Long
    Dim lngCols As Long

    Dim lngR As Long
    Dim lngC As Long

    Dim varValues() As Variant

    Set rngCurrent = Selection

    lngRows = rngCurrent.Rows.Count
    lngCols = rngCurrent.Columns.Count

    ReDim varValues(0 To lngRows - 1, 0 To lngCols - 1) As Variant

    For lngR = 0 To lngRows - 1
        For lngC = 0 To lngCols - 1
            varValues(lngR, lngC) = lngR * lngCols + lngC
        Next
    Next

    rngCurrent.Value = varValues
End Sub
```